# Top Questions of the Week #28

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 28 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Liked this

> [Remotely turning on or rebooting a frozen computer](https://superuser.com/questions/319859/remotely-turning-on-or-rebooting-a-frozen-computer)

---

> I use a remote desktop program (usually Microsoft's Remote Desktop) to connect to a Windows machine everyday. The remote computer has a fixed IP address, and if the computer is on and responsive, I can reboot the computer remotely to install updates, etc., as well as turn it off.
>
> Unfortunately, if the remote computer freezes (for example, if it gets a blue screen), as far as I know, I can't use a remote desktop solution to restart it. Similarly, if my computer is off, I can't use remote desktop to boot it.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this question because it's well organized, and includes an excellent level of detail:

- [Monitor doesn't come on without a bit of "fiddling"](https://superuser.com/questions/322413/monitor-doesnt-come-on-without-a-bit-of-fiddling)

I also see this question as a suitable example for the FAQ for well-written questions (as this could be useful to newcomers).